# mapView shows alert more than once

Tags: ios7, mkmapview

In my App the `mapView` shows an `UIAlertView` when the map couldn't be loaded. I did this in

```
- (void)mapViewDidFailLoadingMap:(MKMapView *)mapView withError:(NSError *)error {}
```

When I simulate this in Simulator or in my iPhone by turning off WiFi, I get the message. But it shows up twice or more. How can I prevent that everything in this method gets executed several times?

Comment: try to add a breakpoint at that method and check it how many times did  it enter on that method. or just simply log it.

Comment: I have an NSLog for the Alert. It varies between 2 and 3 times that I get the Log as well as the UIAlertView.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`-(void)mapViewDidFailLoadingMap:(MKMapView *)mapView withError:(NSError *)error` this function may get called many times check this Apple Docs

`This method might be called in situations where the device does not have access to the network or is unable to load the map data for some reason. It may also be called if a request for additional map tiles comes in while a previous request for tiles is still pending. You can use this message to notify the user that the map data is unavailable`

check for the exact reason why it is getting called multiple times.. Also you can avoid showing multiple alertViews by using some flag or by using UIAlertView property `visible`

Comment: Thanks for your help. I found the reason. In another method I updated the region of the mapView. I just needed to set the BOOL that causes the map to update to NO.

Answer (score 0):

you can use [UIAlertView isVisible] before you display your alertview, this will prevent you on displaying multiple alertview when alertview is already shown.